# Exclusion script Journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I want to use an exclusion script.
DE is called a Journeylog with attributes "Journey",  "pression", and "subcriberkey"

I want to exclude
subscribers who have journey = x and pression = 1
How should I write the function? so;

```
%% [ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Journeylog", "Journey", "x","Subscriberkey",_subscriberkey, "pression","1")) >0] %%
```

I've never worked on script exclusion I accept any advice.

Comment: Ps. Also for future, AMPscript block tags need to be written withou any speces between the percent sign and the square bracket, like this: `%%[`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script looks good, just remove the AMPscript block tags and use this in the Exclusion Script box:

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Journeylog", "Journey", "x","Subscriberkey",_subscriberkey, "pression","1")) >0
```

I am assmuing you will replace the x with an actual journey name.